# JuliaPro v0.6.2.2. does not provide the line number of the error in the REPL

Tags: ide, julia, atom-editor

I am using the new version atoms for **JULIA language** JuliaPro v0.6.2.2 in windows 10. I am finding that in the **REPL** when I get an error for e.g.

```
    ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching 
    setcharheight(::Float64)The applicable method may be too new: running in 
    world age 21685, while current world is 21686.
```

I do not get the **line number** of the error to help me to take action as in the previous version. So how can I get the location of the error?

Comment: Are you plotting with GR? Is it [this](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1047) issue?

Comment: The downvoter *really* needs to explain the downvote. This seems like a perfectly good question to me. I'll upvote back to 0. Regarding the error, is it *only* for world age errors that you're having this problem, or are other types of errors also not providing the line number? eg if you put `error("blerg")` in your code somewhere, do you get the line number in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I am using GR which is an issue sometimes which I will tackle in another question. To answer the question of Colin below is the code and the error associated which gives me the wrong number. It seems like that Julia is disconnected to the IDE JuliaPro:

```
    **1 function Test():
    2    println("Testing")
    3    error("blerg")
    4    println("End of Testing")
    5 end
    6
    7 Test()**
```

When I run JuliaPro I get the following answer which gives me the wrong number of the error lign of the code:

```
 **ERROR: LoadError: syntax: space not allowed after ":" used for quoting
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::Atom.##110#114{String,String})() at C:\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.2\v0.6\Atom\src\eval.jl:104
 [2] withpath(::Atom.##110#114{String,String}, ::String) at C:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.2\v0.6\CodeTools\
src\utils.jl:30
 [3] withpath(::Function, ::String) at C:\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.2\v0.6\Atom\src\eval.jl:38
 [4] hideprompt(::Atom.##109#113{String,String}) at C:\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.2\v0.6\Atom\src\repl.j
l:65
 [5] macro expansion at C:\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.2\v0.6\Atom\src\eval.jl:99 [inlined]
 [6] (::Atom.##108#112{Dict{String,Any}})() at .\task.jl:80
while loading C:\JOE\Main\MODELS\SOIL\BEST\Test.jl, in expression starting **on line 2****
```